# Why wiki.ros.org downs frequently?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.isup.me/wiki.ros.org

Says:

> It's not just you! http://wiki.ros.org
> looks down from here.

In these days, downs frequently. For example just now. Anyone knows why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258781/why-wiki.ros.org-downs-frequently?/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're actively investigating this right now. No updates yet, but we've restarted Apache a few times already today to try to keep things alive while we search for the root cause.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of the different ROS sites are hosted on different servers (which is why answers.ros.org is up when the wiki is down).

ROS tracks the site uptimes on http://status.ros.org/#month , and it looks like the wiki and some other sites have been down this morning, but over the past month they're over 98% uptime, so I wouldn't call that "downs frequently".

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4